# Matching regex after colon but before underscore

Tags: regex

I have two strings below which i need to apply a regex function to in Google BigQuery with its desired outputs: Input:

```
MERCURE ENGAGEMENT_LaL_FB_TALENT:HENRIQUE_PORTUGAL_WEEK 4_IMAGE CAROUSEL_I19 
MERCURE ENGAGEMENT_LaL_FB_UGC:_ENGLAND_TBC_WEEK 4_IMAGE CAROUSEL_I25
```

Output:

```
HENRIQUE 
ENGLAND
```

I cannot use a reverse or positive look ahead within bigquery.

The closest I have gotten is the following:

```
:\D*
```

Which matches the word after the colon but before the white space.

Any ideas helpful

Comment: You could use a capturing group `:_?([^\s_]+)` https://regex101.com/r/3fRZ1O/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Does this allow me to have the full match of the word?

Comment: From what I read on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) you can use REGEXP_EXTRACT which will return the value of the capturing group, which will be the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also use a capturing group with with [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract).

```
:_?([^\s_]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `:_?` Match `:` and an optional underscore
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s_]+` Match 1+ times any char other than a whitespace char or an underscore (Omit `\s` if there can also be spaces in between)
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3fRZ1O/1)

You could also exclude matching an underscore from a word character which narrows down the range of accepted characters.

```
:_?([^\W_]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, r'^.*:_?([^_]+)_.*$', r'\1') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT("column_name", r":[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+)")
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/CUG3Wp/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^a-zA-Z]*               any character except: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                           'Z' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```